# How to provide dynamic HTML in PHP?

Tags: php, image, html, dynamic-content

I've got a HTML file which I've created and is stored in a directory elsewhere.

The problem is, I'd like to be able to get content externally and place it within the HTML file.

I figured I could use PHP for this, because it's server-side and can access the files I want.

So, I created a PHP script which opens and echoes a HTML file, and afterwards, echos some JavaScript to change elements that are on the screen.

Here's my PHP file:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('file.html');

$imageurl = file_get_contents('url.txt');

$js = '<script type=\'text/javascript\'>updateImage(\'img1\', '.$imageurl.');</script>';

echo $html;

echo $js;

?>
```

..and the HTML file:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateImage(id, url) {
    var img = document.getElementsByName(id)[0];
    img.src = url;
}
</script>

<body>

<img src="" name="img1" />

</body>

</html>
```

It's not the best method, but it works.

I would like to know a way to do this within PHP, not using JavaScript.

I'm not sure as of the best approach to this.

Comment: do you know what PHP is? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `include` and [ob_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) to get the html as string and do some `str_replace` or `preg_replace` on that.

Your HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="{IMAGE_SRC}" width="512" height="512" name="image" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Your PHP:

```
ob_start();
include 'your_file.html';
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$buffer = str_replace('{IMAGE_SRC}', 'your_image.png', $buffer);

print $buffer;
```

Comment: BTW, this also works with `<?php print $someVariable; ?>` or `<?= $someVariable; ?>` as stated by Chris in the other answer. That's why I prefer `ob_get_contents` over `file_get_contents` for such things.

Answer (score 0):

That is a pretty basic question. You should read some PHP and HTML Tutorials. Something like this will do the trick:

```
<html>

<body>
<img src="" width="512" height="512" name="<?= $somePhpVariableContainingTheName ?>" />
</body>

</html>
```